# Failed To push my code on Github using Gitbash

Tags: github, git-bash

im using gitbash to upload my code to github but it giving below error:

////

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 
'https://github.com/MayurBagul/Weather-Informer.git'
 hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is 
 behind
 hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
 hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
 hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for 
 details.
```

i tried to use fetch and merge command but even though it is giving error.
please help me to solve this issue.

Thanking You,
Mayur Bagul.

i tried to upload my code files using gitbash and it giving error .which is mentioned in problem.

\\

```
$ git push origin master
To https://github.com/MayurBagul/Weather-Informer.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 
'https://github.com/MayurBagul/Weather-Informer.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is 
behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for 
details.
```

\\

i expect my code should get upload to my github repository

Comment: Looks like the local master branch is behind the origin master branch. To help determine a path forward, first question: are other people committing to that branch?